# REACT JS - Number of elements based input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm workin' on a small metronome app in React and I got stuck over a little problem. I'd like to create as many `<Beats>` as the input value says but I don't know how to approach this.

Please check out the [layout idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef8iX.png) for example.

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

This is the structure diagram.

```
Time_Signature_and_Beats_Holder
              |
              ├╌╌Time_Signature_Control
              |
              └╌╌Beats_Holder
                      |
                      └╌╌ Beats
```

Short snippet:

```
class Beat_Holder extends React.Component {
      render(){
        return(


          /*

            Render <Beat index={i} /> component this.props.NoFBeats times

          */


        )
      }
    }
```

Whole piece:

```
class Time_Signature_and_Beats_Holder extends React.Component {

  constructor()
  {
    super()
    this.state = {
      Beats: 4
    }
  }

  //Callback function for number of elements I wanna generate

  Get_Beats(Number_Of_Beats){
        this.setState({Beats: Number_Of_Beats});
        console.log(Number_Of_Beats);
    }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Time_Signature_Control
          onGetBeats={this.Get_Beats.bind(this)}
        />
        <Beat_Holder NoFBeats = {this.state.Beats}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Time_Signature_Control extends React.Component {

  constructor()
  {
    let beats = 5;
    super();
    this.state = {value:beats}
  }

  handleChange(event)
  {
    let beats = event.target.value;
    this.setState({value: beats});
    this.props.onGetBeats(beats);
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <div classname="Time_Signature_Control">
        <p>Time Signature:</p>
        <input type="number" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} id="bpme" min="2" max="50"></input>
          /
        <select id="Note_Length" name="Note">
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="32">32</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Beat_Holder extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(


      /*

        Render <Beat index={i} /> component this.props.NoFBeats times

      */


    )
  }
}

class Beat extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <li>{this.props.index}</li>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically create an array with React elements and use that to render:

```
render() {

    const children = [...Array(this.state.Beats).keys()].map(beat => <Beat prop1={beat} />)

    return (
        <div>
            <Time_Signature_Control onGetBeats={this.Get_Beats.bind(this)}/>
            {children}
         </div> 
    )

}
```

By updating state.Beats more will be automatically added